# Buy Till You Die(BTYD) Model Validation in R

Tags: r

I ran the BTYD package in R which predicts the number of transactions that a customer is expected to make in the future.These expected values that I get are not integers but are in the form 0.14, 0.79, 1.85, etc. In reality, however a customer will only make integral number of transactions - I have this data as well. My question is - how do I validate the performance of my model? What tests can I use to check that my model is predicting close enough results. Or is there a maximum likelihood function that will give me integral values of my Expected transactions through which I can compare the actual and expected results?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I know the post is rather old, but just in case you are still interested... The decimal values are fine, if you want integers round in a smart way, but my suggestion would be to stick with the decimal.

For the validation, usually you need a dataset of past data which you split in two: the first half of the dataset can be used to calibrate the model (you derive the four parameters of the BTYD), while you test it on the second half of the dataset and you see the actual trend vs the predicted trend.

You can find examples on how to compare actual trends vs predicted trends on the guide here:
[BTYD walkthrough](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/BTYD/vignettes/BTYD-walkthrough.pdf)

Good luck